# How to determine the Fermi energy?

Tags: graphene, fermi-energy

[image]

In the figure below the Fermi energy is at zero or at -0.5??

Comment: How on earth one could know that if there is no labeling of axes, no notion of the material, how many electrons in unit cell etc.

Comment: the figure above is band structure graphene nanoribbons, x axes kpoints and y axes E(ev). The number of electrons in unit cell is  6.

Comment: What is the incomplete blue trace at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

In solid state calculations, usually Fermi-level is fitted such that the occupation numbers add up to the total number of electrons.

$$\sum_k \sum_n 2 w_k f(\epsilon_{kn}-\epsilon_f) = N_e $$

One calculates the lhs with different values of $\epsilon_f$ until this equation is fullfulled. Here, f is the Fermi-Dirac function. And $w_k$ is the integration weight of a k-point. 2 comes from spin-degeneracy.

Since, by usual normalization convention, $\sum w_k = 1$, one can estimate that one band below Fermi-level corresponds to two electrons. Thus, if you know the number of electrons in your unit cell, you can get a rough idea where your Fermi-level is just by counting the bands. This works perfectly for insulators and semiconductors, but not for metals since some bands are only partially occupied. In such case, one just has to find the Fermi-level by solving the equation.

Comment: Good comments, but not an answer.